# LLDB thinks function call is ambiguous, but it's not

Tags: c++, lldb

I'm trying to debug a C++ program. I'm on macOS, using CLion IDE, clang compiler, LLDB. I stop the program at a breakpoint (marked with `>>`):

```cpp
UnicodeString unicodeFromFile(const std::string &file) {
    std::ifstream input(file, std::ios::binary);
    cout << "open? " << input.is_open() << endl;
>>  std::vector<char> bytes(...);
```

I want to run `po input.is_open()`. LLDB reports:

```
(lldb) po input.is_open()
error: expression failed to parse:
error: <user expression 0>:1:7: call to member function 'is_open' is ambiguous
input.is_open()
~~~~~~^~~~~~~
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX12.3.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/fstream:1169:10: candidate function
    bool is_open() const;
         ^
```

But it's obviously not ambiguous, since the previous line of code calls it without problem. And it's error message is only listing one function.

Previous to this, I had a different problem where it couldn't find the symbol at all. But I used the [advice here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70445481/error-couldnt-lookup-symbols-when-calling-an-stl-method-in-lldb), which got me to this point. That answer says to add this to to `~/.lldbinit`:

```
settings set target.import-std-module true
```

My previous errors looked like:

```
(lldb) po input.is_open()
error: expression failed to parse:
error: Couldn't lookup symbols:
  __ZNKSt3__114basic_ifstreamIcNS_11char_traitsIcEEE7is_openEv
```

Comment: Try assigning the result of `input.is_open()` to a temporary `bool` variable and place the `bool` variable into the `cout` statement.

Comment: Same error claiming it's "ambiguous".

Answer (score 0):

When I try this trivial case with the most recent Xcode (or with TOT lldb) calling the `is_open` works:

```
 > cat tryifstream.cpp 
#include <fstream>

int
main() {
  std::ifstream my_str("/tmp/tryifstream.cpp");
  bool is_it = my_str.is_open();
  return is_it ? 0 : 20; 
}
> clang++ -g -O0 /tmp/tryifstream.cpp -o /tmp/a.out
> lldb /tmp/a.out
(lldb) b s -p return
Breakpoint 1: where = a.out`main + 88 at tryifstream.cpp:7:10, address = 0x000000010000379c
(lldb) run
Process 38065 launched: '/tmp/a.out' (arm64)
Process 38065 stopped
* thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = breakpoint 1.1
    frame #0: 0x000000010000379c a.out`main at tryifstream.cpp:7
   4    main() {
   5      std::ifstream my_str("/tmp/tryifstream.cpp");
   6      bool is_it = my_str.is_open();
-> 7      return is_it ? 0 : 20; 
                 ^
   8    }
Target 0: (a.out) stopped.
(lldb) v is_it
(bool) is_it = true
(lldb) expr my_str.is_open()
(bool) $0 = true
```

If this simple case fails for you, you might try upgrading your Xcode.  Getting the lldb expression parser to handle all of std templates is an area of ongoing work and newer lldb's are generally better at it.

If that simple case works for you, but your "real" case still doesn't, and you can make your project or some reduced reproducer available to us, please file a bug with the llvm.org bug reporter, including a copy of your reproducer.  It will be hard to figure out what's going wrong in this case w/o being able to trace through the lookups.

Comment: Did you add that line to ~/.lldbinit? If I do that, your minimal example fails for me. I have the latest Xcode (pre-release of 14). If I remove the line from .lldbinit, it works, but I added it for the reason mentioned in the question.

Comment: Ah, interesting - definitely a bug.  The error you were getting was because the compiler ONLY emitted an inline copy of `is_open` and lldb can't call inline instances.  We can build the function from the imported std module however - that's why that setting helps.  However, with recent clangs the expression works w/o it because clang++ actually emits a function for `ifstream::is_open`.  You can verify this by running nm on your binary.  But apparently when you import std we end up with the generated copy from the module, and the emitted one - and don't grok the duplication.